# Ошибка в библиотеке numpy. Невозможность перегрузить метод __radd__

Tags: python, numpy

Столкнулся с необходимостью перегрузки метода `__radd__` для своего класса и понял, что numpy.array не поддерживает это. Вот что я имею ввиду:
Объявлен класс A:

```
class A:
    def __radd__(self, val):
        print(f'val = {val}, type = {type(val)}')

import numpy as np
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [-4, 3, 45]])
a = A()
b + a
```

Выводит:

```
val = 1, type = <class 'int'>
val = 2, type = <class 'int'>
val = 3, type = <class 'int'>
val = -4, type = <class 'int'>
val = 3, type = <class 'int'>
val = 45, type = <class 'int'>
```

Что явно не является ожидаемым поведением... Значит в `__add__` `np.array` прописано нечто, что не даёт нормально пользоваться перегрузкой `__radd__` в классах.

Comment: А попробуйте поменять на: `def __add__(self, val):` и `a + b`

Comment: Я пробовал. Это не то, что мне нужно. Я хочу написать класс, который не будет падать, когда его вызовут не так, как задумал разработчик.

Comment: `Что явно не является ожидаемым поведением` - а что является ожидаемым поведением? Скорее всего у `np.array` метод `__add__` перегружен таким образом, что + применяется к каждому элементу массива, а потом все собирается в общий массив. Это нужно чтобы работали операции типа `b + 5`.

Comment: Radd насколько я помню вызывается, когда у второго не объявлен add. Но я так. А какое все таки ожидаемое поведение?

Comment: Я ожидал, что в val я получу экземпляр матрицы, с которым смогу работать.

Comment: @Chudvan, значит вам придется переопределить array и его `__add__`.

Comment: Кстати, вот пример, демонстрирующий такое же поведение как np.array: https://ideone.com/nV5UQg

Comment: `Я хочу написать класс, который не будет падать, когда его вызовут не так, как задумал разработчик.` - это из области фантастики (ну или надо реализовать мощный ИИ). И кстати, что должно получиться если к вашему объекту попытаются прибавить объект пользовательского класса о котором ваш класс ничего не знает?

Comment: Понял, ваш пример. Подскажите, возможно ли тогда переопределить свой класс матрицу, который будет способен адекватно складываться с np.array, стоя справа?